# $P$ is positive definite and $A=PA^*P^{-1}$ $\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? \sigma (A) \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,P\in {M_n}$, and $P$ is positive definite and $A=PA^*P^{-1}$.

Is this true that, all eigenvalue of $A$ is real?

Comment: If $P$ is only semidefinite, it may not be invertible. Is $A^*$ the conjugate transpose of $A$?

Comment: @Vuser251257 - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $P$ is invertible.

Note that $PA^* = AP$.  Because $P$ is Hermitian, we have
$$
(AP)^* = AP
$$
so that $AP$ is Hermitian.

---

From there, apply the steps in the comment below: $AP$ is Hermitian, so $P^{-1/2}AP^{1/2}$ is Hermitian, so $A$ is similar to a Hermitian matrix.

Comment: Since $AP$ is hermitian, so is $P^{-1/2}(AP) P^{-1/2} = P^{-1/2} A P^{1/2}$.

Comment: Aha! There it is, well done.